# Resetting Score In Restart of Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a VR game, in which there is only one level which is on main scene and the other scene is of "end" on which the game Over text Score is visible with Restart(which reloads the main scene) and Exit Button.

My problem is, M using this script as my `ScoreManager` script given below. I want this score in end scene too and this is working as m using `PlayerPrefs`

But the main problem is, when clicking the restart at the end scene, the game reloads the Main scene but that score Still have the same value of the previous game. I want it to set to Zero.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

namespace CompleteProject
{
    public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static int score ;        // The player's score.
        Text text;                      // Reference to the Text component.

        void Awake()
        {
            // Set up the reference.
            text = GetComponent<Text>();
            score = 0;
            score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score");
        }

        void Update ()
        {

            // Set the displayed text to be the word "Score" followed by the score value.
            text.text = "Score: " + score;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", score);

        }
    }
}
```

I have also used `DeleteKey(string)` to delete the score, but nothing happened.

Comment: Why use `PlayerPrefs` if you want the score to reset in the next level?

Answer (score 1):

You said you tried `DeleteKey(int score)`  but it didn't work. Your code does **not** have the `DeleteKey` function anywhere. If you don't know how to use that function, the code below will show you how to use it. If you actually know how to use it but it's not working as mentioned in your question, then call `PlayerPrefs.Save()` after it. This should delete the key and update it right away.

To reset the score after each game, put the code in the `OnDisable()` function.

```
void OnDisable()
{
    PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("Score");
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

To reset it when game begins, get the current `score` like you did in the `Awake()` function then change the function above to `OnEnable()`.

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply ,   i have two scene here, one is main scene and one is end scene , when am playing game am in main scene score is properly updating and showing score whenever i killed enemy , but when player health get zero End  scene get lodes it is also displaying the score whatever player earns score in main scene, but when user /player restart the game the previous score is also displaying in main scene , that's the issue ,whenever player restart the game main scene collects previous played score and add it in main scene score board,

Comment: i did what ever you said , it make end scene score value "0"  and one more thing  i am using same script for  both the scene , thanks for helping me

Comment: Isn't `Awake` called only once, when the object is instantiated? From what I remember `Start` is called on every scene change which could be a solution if scene is reloaded.

Comment: @Mateusz Both `Awake` and `Start` are called once on an object. Note that I asked OP to change the `Awake` to `OnEnable`.

Comment: @Programmer Okay, thank you for explanation. I wasn't just sure about these.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you still get the previous session of your score so you need to reset the saved values by resetting the value back to zero ,by using the line :

### PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", 0);

```
 public static int score ;       
        Text text;             
        void Start(){

            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", 0);
            // Set up the reference.
            text = GetComponent<Text>();
            score = 0;
            score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score",0);
        }
        void Update ()
        {

            // Set the displayed text to be the word "Score" followed by the score value.
            text.text = "Score: " + score;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", score);

        }
```

Comment: Dumping code even if it fixes the issue is not going to help anyone besides OP. StackOverflow is generaly a knowledge sharing platform on which every solution should be described at least in some small sentences. Add any explanation on what have you changed to fix the issue and if possible explain why this issue occured.